# How to create full screen activity in ionic type 1 Application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

How can we create fullscreen activity in ionic type 1 application for Android? I want to hide status bar in ionic type 1 application and want to create the fullscreen login activity.

Comment: Have you tried using [this plugin](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen)? It is also available via [ionic-native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen/)

Comment: Assuming your using the StatusBar plugin, it might be even simpler: Just use `if (window.StatusBar) {StatusBar.hide();}` in the `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback...